# Trigger to run a MySQL query when a row is inserted or deleted

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to run this query each time a new row is added or deleted

```
UPDATE brandnames updated
JOIN (select bname, count(*) as cnt 
from brandnames 
group by bname) aggregate 
ON updated.bname= aggregate.bname
set `count`= aggregate.cnt
```

Please help me with a trigger entry for this. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'd say [you cannot](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.5/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already
>   being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the
>   function or trigger.

Comment: :( Means there's no way to automatically run this above MySQL entry when a row is added or deleted?

Comment: Not from a trigger against `brandnames`.

Comment: Would the same thing apply if you created two triggers?  One to a temp table and then another trigger on that temp table back to the original table?

Comment: So umm is there any other way to do so?

Comment: @JasonSperske HOPE! May what you said is right. There must be a way to do so. :(